# Proof for new deterministic primality test

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Claim:

> Let $p$ be a positive prime. Let $n \in \left\{1, 2, 3, ...\right\}$. Then $N =
> p\cdot 2^n+1$ is prime, if and only if it holds the congruence $3^{(N-1)/2} \equiv \pm1\ ($mod $N)$.

If the claim is true, we would have a fast deterministic test for numbers of the form $p\cdot2^n + 1$. That means, with small $p$ and large $n$, we could generate huge prime numbers, similar to Mersenne primes or Fermat primes.

A proof is needed. Thanks for Your attention.

Comment: What led you to this claim?

Comment: Is one of the implications true?

Comment: Seems to be related to [a question by Tony Reix](http://mathoverflow.net/q/216174/41291)

Comment: Did a quick check, seems to hold for first 90 primes $p$ and $n\leqslant 20$

Comment: (Well to be precise, checked against $3^{N-1}\equiv1\mod N$)

Comment: Criterion can not replaced by $3^{N-1}\equiv 1 ($mod $N)$ because there is a counter example. $N =356387⋅2^{11}+1=12289⋅59393$ while $3^{N−1}≡1($mod$N)$

Comment: OMG will check with precise criterion then. How far did you check it?

Comment: Why downvote seems like Guest_2015 is chasing good leads here.

Comment: How do you generate primes fast? The test works for Mersenne primes and you are working modulo large $N$?

Comment: Now checking with the precise criterion, currently reached $n$ up to $14$ with first $3000$ primes (the $3000$th prime is $27449$). However this seems to be not much of an evidence in view of the above example with $p=356387$.

Comment: Modulo errors there are no counterexamples for $p \le 10^7, n \le 10^2$.

Comment: $p=2$ gives $N=2^k+1$. Has anyone tested primality for numbers of form $N=2^{2^k}+1$? It is conjectured there are only finitely many of these. May be this will be helpful to find a false prime

Comment: @Arul For Fermat numbers, OP's question is Pepin's test.

Comment: You: _That means, with small $p$ and large $n$, we could generate huge prime numbers_ We already have [Proth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem) which allows us to find huge prime of this form (even when the initial odd multiplier is not prime). This has been used for example to establish that numbers thought to be [non-Sierpiński](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) (because of lack of any obvious covering sets) were in fact so. Maybe someone can comment on the relationship between Proth's theorem and your conjecture above?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński The "only if" direction is obvious because of Fermat's little theorem and the fact that $1$ cannot have other square roots than $\pm 1$ inside $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$ (this group is cyclic of order $N-1$ when $N$ is prime).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen -- thank you. *** (Not all my q's are hard :-) ).

Comment: Just for the record, the question was cross-posted to MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410031

Answer (score 30):

The claim does not hold. A counterexample is given by $n=14$, $p=134123250258009499$ and correspondingly
$$N = 2197475332227227631617 = 193 \cdot 12289 \cdot 926510094425921.$$
It can be easily verified that
$$3^{(N-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{N},$$
but $N$ is not prime.

---

A couple more values of $N$ giving counterexamples:
$$300334937065845770469377,\ 80203520301265852381167617.$$

**ADDED.** Here is a [list of 659 counterexamples](https://gist.github.com/maxale/b09e4ac7889dccb1706db9bff17dbc3b) that I composed from the [known prime factors](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN03.html) of generalized Fermat numbers GFN(3).

Comment: How did you guess?

Comment: @Turbo: I composed them from [known prime factors](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFNfacs.html) of generalized Fermat numbers $3^{2^k}+1$.

Answer (score 12):

@Igor Rivin

I will answer Your question here. I have done a research about safe primes, and I have found a new deterministic primality test for safe primes. This test goes as follows: We have two statements:

> 1.) Let $p=3$ (mod $4$) be prime. $2p+1$ is also prime if and only if $2p+1$ divides $2^p−1$.
>
> 2.) Let $p=1$ (mod $4$) be prime. $2p+1$ is also prime if and only if $2p+1$ divides $2^p+1$.

(Statement 1. is proven by Lagrange 1775, and statement 2. is [proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359970/prove-for-2p-1-divides-2p-1) by Batominovsky 2015)

So if a number $N=2\cdot p+1$ holds the congruence $2^p\equiv \pm1\ ($mod $N)$ then it is definitely prime.

From this point I went one step further to $N=p\cdot2^n + 1$.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I could prove it in the case of a negative sign but I can only show that in this case, for fixed $n$, there can be only finitely many counterexamples. Nothing magical about $3$ by the way.

Let $p$ be prime and $n$ an integer such that $N=2^np + 1$ is such that, for some integer $a$ we have $a^{(N-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod N$. Then $N$ is prime or $p \le a^{2^{n-1}}/2^n$.

Proof: Let $m$ be the order of $a$ modulo $N$, then $m | 2^np$, so $m = 2^k$ or $2^kp$ for some $k \le n$. Since we have $-1$ in the congruence in the hypothesis, we conclude that $k=n$. If $m = 2^np$, then $N$ is prime ($\phi(N)=N-1$ iff $N$ is prime). The only other possibility is $m=2^n$. Assume that's the case. Then $2^n | \phi(N)$ but we cannot have $p|\phi(N)$ as that would force $\phi(N) \ge N-1$. So $(p,\phi(N))=1$ and the congruence $a^{(N-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod N$, then implies that $a^{2^{n-1}} \equiv -1 \pmod N$. So $N \le a^{2^{n-1}} + 1$ giving the result.

Comment: There are counterexamples to primality with $a$ other than $3$. For instance $p=157,n=2,N=4p+1=629=17\cdot 37$ and $a=191$ satisfies $a^2 \equiv -1 \pmod N$.

Comment: So $a=3$ is special?

Comment: Maybe you want to exclude $a= -1$ or the congruence?

Comment: @joro I guess $a=-1$ needs to be excluded for $n=1$. In fact, $a$ needs to be positive if $n=1$, so the inequality at the end works. For $n>1$, $a$ is raised to an even power, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, this what I meant. You mean $a \not \equiv -1 \pmod{N}$?.

Comment: @joro If $a>N$ and $n=1$ then $p \le a/2$.

Comment: Don't understand this. $a$ can be anything and the last inequality doesn't appear to be of _practical_ usage when $p$ is given prime, no matter of $a$.

Comment: @joro The result is more interesting when you fix $n$ and vary $p$ than vice-versa.

Comment: When $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1 \bmod N$, Felipe's observation that $2^n$ divides $\varphi(n)$ does imply that the number of non-Fermat prime divisors of $N$ is bounded for fixed $p$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$.